# Multiple WHERE's in same LINQ 2 SQL Method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the below LINQ Method I am trying to create.  The issue seems to be the Second WHERE clause.  I am getting this error -->

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MatrixReloaded.Data.CMO.tblWorkerHistory>' to 'bool'`

I also had `&&` there vs `WHERE` but I was getting a similar error.  I don't NEED anything from `tblWorkerHistories` except the `EndDate` stuff.

There is a *Many To Many relationship* between the 2 tables with `EnrollmentID` being a **FK** on both.

```
public static DataTable GetCurrentWorkersByEnrollmentID(int enrollmentID)
    {
        using (var context = CmoDataContext.Create())
        {
            context.Log = Console.Out;

            var currentWorkers = from enrollment in context.tblCMOEnrollments
                                 where enrollment.EnrollmentID == enrollmentID
                                 where enrollment.tblWorkerHistories.Where(a => a.EndDate == null || a.EndDate > DateTime.Now)
                                 select
                                     new
                                         {
                                             enrollment.CMONurseID,
                                             enrollment.CMOSocialWorkerID,
                                             SupportWorkerName = enrollment.tblSupportWorker.FirstName + " " + enrollment.tblSupportWorker.LastName,
                                             SupportWorkerPhone = enrollment.tblSupportWorker.Phone
                                         };

            return currentWorkers.CopyLinqToDataTable();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
where enrollment.tblWorkerHistories.Where(/* stuff */)
```

`Where` returns a sequence... whereas you need something that will return a Boolean value. What are you trying to do with that embedded `Where` clause?

As Marc says, it *could* be that you just need an `Any` call instead of `Where`... but if you could explain what you're trying to do, that would make it a lot easier to help you. Note that `Any` *does* return a Boolean value, instead of a sequence.

EDIT: Okay, so in SQL you'd use a join, but you don't need an explicit join here because LINQ is implicitly doing that for you, right? If you're trying to find enrollments where *any* of the histories match the date, and you don't care about the histories themselves, then `Any` is indeed what you want:

```
var currentWorkers = from enrollment in context.tblCMOEnrollments
                     where enrollment.EnrollmentID == enrollmentID
                     where enrollment.tblWorkerHistories.Any
                           (a => a.EndDate == null || a.EndDate > DateTime.Now)
                     select ...
```

Comment: In SQL terms I am trying to do this --> `FROM tblWorkerHistory h
 inner join tblCMOEnrollment e
  on h.EnrollmentID = e.EnrollmentID
WHERE h.EnrollmentID = anINTHere AND (h.EndDate IS NULL) OR (h.EndDate > GetDate())
`

Comment: I am trying to limit my results set from `tblCMOEnrollments` based of the EndDate field in `tblWorkerHistories`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.   Side Note, is there a difference between using a second WHERE and &&?  They both seem to work....

Comment: @Refracted Paladin: No, they should basically do the same thing. I tend to use multiple where clauses for logically separate conditions, and && for multiple bits of the same logical condition.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you mean `.Any` instead of `.Where` in the sub-query; the outermost `.Where` (i.e. the second `where`) expects a *predicate* expression, but yours is currently a *selector* - try:

```
where enrollment.tblWorkerHistories.Any(
      a => a.EndDate == null || a.EndDate > DateTime.Now)
```